# How much data that Mongodb can hold

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I'm using MongoDB NoSQL Database for my project and using MongoDB compass to visualize data. When I'm trying to insert data into the database, documents are inserted at the console level. But I could not see the same data in MongoDB compass. is there a specific size for MongoDB compass?

Info about my MongoDB database: Total size: 36.9 MB and 900.3k Documents

Comment: Are you able to see at least a few documents, may be inserted earlier? Are you working with a capped collection ? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/

Comment: No, i see just the last ones

Comment: MongoDB does not have a limit on data size. Whatever it is you're experiencing, it's not related to restrictions of the database technology.